# Oracle SOA taskflow deployed but not available in worklist

Tags: soa, jdeveloper, weblogic12c

I have been working with Oracle SOA Suit 12c human task component. However, I have created a simple bpel processs that takes one input for human intervention and response required by the user assigned. The project deployed successfully to weblogic domain soa_server1. Now the web service is being tested by oracle em->soa_server->composite application. When the user login to worklist, the task is being populated but when he clicks on task, it shows a login form rathar than the huam task form(the jsf/jspx) page.

**Additional Details**
Weblogic Server 12c, SOA Quick Start 12c(12.2.2.1.0) installed and weblogic domain configured using database. JDeveloper version 12c.

*Below is the screenshot of worklist*

[image]

Can anyone please look in to this, what's the issue??

Comment: Hi Gaurav any update you have on this facing same issue??

Comment: Hi Raj , pls check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was related to user assignment in Human Task dedinition.

1. Double click on human task in your composite.
2. Go to assignments(user assignment)
3. My mistake-  I had set the owner as weblogic and trying to access the task in worklist with user 'level1'

SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME

Either leave blank to owner text filed or specify all users whom task is being assigned or users who manually clam task.

I haven't tried but probably of you have hierarchy set for users then it might require only top level person to be specified in owner section.

Comment: I have assigned it to correct user but i am still facing the issue

Comment: Inside General tab of Human Task- please leave 'owner' field blank.Now inside assignment tab -> Approval->Stage->Participant List-> Specify using Names and expressions-> Value Based and give static value of user(should be available in your LDAP or try giving 'weblogic' for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I had a different issue the url in the humantask configuration was pointing to some random name and not the server host name changing that worked